# Results between two dates in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm looking to get data between two dates in elasticsearch.
I have tried to put `"gte": "20-04-2019"` and `"lte": "21-04-2019"` as shown below, but I still get other anterior dates in the final result:

```
GET aws-index2/produit/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "commun.nom": {
              "query": "iphone",
              "operator": "and",
              "zero_terms_query": "all"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "commun.date": {
              "gte": "20-04-2019",
              "lte": "21-04-2019",
              "format": "dd-MM-yyyy"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: May you please provide an example of resulting documents which were matched wrongly?

Comment: @NikolayVasiliev i made my answer in a comment please reformat it, i'm not good with text editing. thx

Answer (score 0):

In the sample document you give, `commun.date` looks like this `"04-20-2019"`, which means that the format is not `dd-MM-yyyy` but `MM-dd-yyyy`. So your query should probably look like this instead:

```
GET aws-index2/produit/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "commun.nom": {
              "query": "iphone",
              "operator": "and",
              "zero_terms_query": "all"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "commun.date": {
              "gte": "04-20-2019",
              "lte": "04-21-2019"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```